# PHP warns inherited function declaration as incompatible

Tags: php, oop

I have a strange warning concerning PHP strict standards in my debug.log.

```
PHP Strict standards:  Declaration of gb_EntryList::fields() should be compatible with mgr_LinearModelCollection::fields($mKey = NULL) in ... on line 339
```

So far so bad, but line 339 holds the definition of the `gb_EntryList` class

```
class gb_EntryList extends mgr_mySQLModel
```

and `gb_EntryList` does not define `fields()` at all. It inherits this from `mgr_mySQLModel`:

```
abstract class mgr_mySQLModel extends mgr_LinearModelCollection implements mgr_mySQLModelUpdateable {
   ...
   function fields($mKey = null) { ... }
}
```

Originally, I forgot to put the `= null` into the declaration, which produced similar messages about `mgr_mySQLModel`. But these are gone now.

The code runs nicely, but what does this message want to tell me?

PHP version:

```
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u5 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2013 09:24:58)
```

**Update:**

I dug a little deeper into the issue. Interestingly the following code should have the same structure, but is fine with `php -d error_reporting=4095 -l`:

```
abstract class A {
  function foo($sText = ""){
     echo "A.foo($sText)\n";
  }
  abstract function bar();
}
abstract class B extends A {
  function foo($sText = ""){
     echo "B.foo($sText)\n";
  }  
}
class C extends B {
  function bar(){
    echo "C.bar()\n";
  }
}

$c = new C();
$c->foo('in C');
```

The actual classes are too big to reproduce them here. But the structure is apart from interface inheritence the same. However, the above code appears to be fine. The actual situation is slightly more complex:

```
abstract class mgr_LinearModelCollection implements IteratorAggregate, Countable, ArrayAccess {
    protected $sItemClass;
    function getIterator() { }      
    function count(){ }
    function offsetExists($offset){ }
    function offsetGet($offset){ }      
    function offsetUnset($offset){ }        
    function offsetSet($offset, $value){ }

    function fields($mKey = null){
        $aDummy = call_user_func(array($this->sItemClass,'dummyArray'),$mKey);
        return array_keys($aDummy);
    }
}
interface mgr_mySQLModelUpdateable {
    static function updateTable(array $aOpts = array());
}
abstract class mgr_mySQLModel extends mgr_LinearModelCollection implements mgr_mySQLModelUpdateable{
    protected $aFieldNames = null;
    function fields($mKey = null){
        if(!is_array($this->aFieldNames)) return false;
        return $this->aFieldNames;
    }
}
class gb_EntryList extends mgr_mySQLModel {
    static function updateTable(array $aOpts = array()){ }
}
```

There are of course many more functions and the `{ }` are filled with code, but apart from that this is the real unchanged code, which produces the said error message. I currently lack any idea, why the toy model is fine, but the real one is not. Any hints?

Comment: Show us the entire gb_EntryList class please, if it's too long, cut irrelevant methods.

Comment: Do any other parents of `gb_EntryList` declare the method `fields`?

Comment: Yes, mgr_mySQLModel::fields() overloads mgr_LinearModelCollection::fields(). There are no more parents, however the top class implements IteratorAggregate, Countable, and ArrayAccess.

Answer (score 1):

This E_STRICT message warns about a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). It means that a method that was already defined in the superclass needs to be callable with the arguments of the method in the superclass.

This will trigger the message:

```
class Super {
  public function foo($argument) {
    echo $argument;
  }
}

class Child extends Super {

  public function foo() {
    parent::foo('bar');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of Child::foo() should be compatible 
with Super::foo($argument) in ... on line 15
```

Comment: I think that should be the case. mgr_LinearModelCollection is the first to define the function. mgr_mySQLModel overloads it, but using the same parameter template. gb_EntryList just inherits, no own definition.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you say that field() is not declared in gb_EntryList is the clue to what's wrong. mgr_mySQLModel is an ABSTRACT class, if you look in the [PHP manual entry for abstract classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) the clue is in the line that says "When inheriting from an abstract class, all methods marked abstract in the parent's class declaration must be defined by the child". So although PHP is magically working out that you want the parent field() method, you really should also be declaring it in the child class too.

Comment: I find it a common problem, people always forget that they are extending an abstract class rather than just a normal class.

Comment: If that was the problem the error message would be very explicitly saying so: http://3v4l.org/ooZ9O

Comment: fields() is not abstract anywhere in the hierarchy.